# C++: Format not a string literal and no format arguments

Tags: c++, char, stack, bison

I've been trying to print a string literal but seems like I'm doing it wrong, since I'm getting a warning on compilation. It's probably due to wrong formatting or my misunderstanding of `c_str()` function, which I assume should return a `string`.

```
parser.y: In function ‘void setVal(int)’:
parser.y:617:41: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
```

Line 617:

```
sprintf(temp, constStack.top().c_str());
```

Having those declarations

```
#include <stack>
const int LENGTH = 15;
char *temp = new char[LENGTH];
stack<string> constStack;
```

How can I provide a proper formating to string?

Comment: Are you only asking about how to disable the warning, or does your code really not do what you expect it to?

Comment: @ChristianHackl, the second option. :)

Comment: I've edited my question to improve it a little, hoping for the downvotes to disappear. If any of you guys gave me the downvote, could I please know the reason why? Which part could I improve? It's a fairly old question. I'm aware of it being a duplicate.

Comment: I did not downvote myself, but I think the main issue with your question is that you did not provide an MCVE. The little code you provide cannot be compiled without a lot of tedious modifications (add a `main` function, add `std::` etc), and it does not even show any use of `c_str()`. This leaves others with *guessing* what your real code might be, which is annoying.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm grateful for your opinion and will try to improve the question based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple - provide a format string:

```
sprintf(temp, "%s", constStack.top().c_str());
```

But much, much better:

```
string temp = constStack.top();
```

Comment: @nobodynoone Please explain how the second one doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: +1 ... or use a std::istringstream object - sprintf() has more security issues that just this.  In this case however the rather obvious `strcpy()` (or better yet `strncpy()`) would also work.

Comment: Then call `c_str()` when you need to.

Comment: @nobodynoone : So what so hard about later using `temp.c_str()` ?

Comment: The second version has at least two fewer bugs than the first.

Comment: @nobodynoone : That hardly makes sense.  You are happy using `std::string` for `constStack.top()`, you only need to convert to a `char*` at the point of interface to code not within your control.  I'm not sure how being a "compiler project" is justification.

Answer (score 4):

You are telling me in your comment that the problem is not so much the warning as the fact that your code doesn't do what you expect it to.

The solution to this and other, similar problems is to get rid of the strong C influence in your C++ code. Specifically, don't use raw dynamically allocated char arrays or `sprintf`. Use `std::string` instead.

In this case, you are using `sprintf` very incorrectly. Have you ever seen its signature? It goes like this:

```
sprintf(char *str, char const *format, ...)
```

`str` *is* the output of the operation. `format` *describes* what the output should be. The rest are the format arguments, which must by pure convention match what's described in `format`.

Now this "rest", written as `...`, means that you can pass any number of arguments, even zero. And this is why your code even compiles (delivering a nice example for why `...` is a dangerous feature, by the way).

In your code, the output string is, possibly incorrectly, your `temp` string. And the format to describe the output is, almost certainly incorrectly, what happens to sit on top of your stack.

Is this just about **assigning** one string to another, using `sprintf` simply because it more or less can do that as a very special case of what its feature set offers? There's no need for such hacks, as C++ has string assignment out of the box with `std::string`:

```
std::string temp = constStack.top();
```

Notice that this also eliminates the need to know the length of the string in advance.

If, for some reason, you really need formatting (but your question doesn't really show any need for it), then learn more about **string streams** as an alternative solution to format strings.

Comment: I could learn some from this ;) Thanks!

Comment: +1 for stringstream, though as you point out it is a good alternative to sprintf, neither is appropriate for what this code appears to be doing - strcpy!

Comment: @Clifford: Yes, it seems that the OP abused sprintf to copy a string. In any case, format strings *can* be the better approach in general, for example when complex output must be localisable for different languages where certain languages might change the order of the individual elements (e.g. "Show %USERNAME%" vs. "%USERNAME% anzeigen" in German). With stream-oriented solutions, the positioning is hard-coded. In this case, one might consider Boost.Format to combine flexibility and type-safety.

Answer (score 3):

As the warning indicates it is issued as a result of the `-Wformat-security` option; you *could* simply disable the warning by removing the option; but it would be perhaps unwise.

The [security issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string) is perhaps theoretical unless your code is to be widely distributed.  Of perhaps more immediate concern is the possibility of your code crashing or behaving abnormally.

The problem is that the string is variable, and may at runtime contain formatting characters that cause it to attempt to read non-existent arguments.  If for example the string is received from user input and the user entered "%s" it would attempt to read a string from some somewhere on the stack.  That would at best place junk in `temp`, but worse if the memory read happened not to contain a nul character in the first 15 bytes, it would overrun temp, and corrupt the heap (in this case).  Heap corruptions are probably worse than stack corruptions - the latent bug can remain unnoticed in your code for a long time only to start crashing after some unrelated change; and if it does crash, it is unlikely to be in any proximity to the cause.

Comment: Great explaination! Appreciated!